# Erasing AutoCAD drawing objects after exploding them, using C#

Tags: c#, automation, autocad

I am working on a Task in which the code automatically opens a drawing selected by the user [in a UI] and selects all the objects in the drawing and starts to explode all the of them till they cant be exploded anymore. While doing this I face a problem, the original (un-exploded 3D object) is still present in the drawing, super imposed by the Exploded object. Every recursive call of the Explode function creates a new exploded 3D object of that object.

Here is a snippet of the code I working on:

```
PromptSelectionResult ss = ed.SelectAll();

using (DocumentLock acLckDoc = doc.LockDocument())
{
  using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
   {
    objs = new DBObjectCollection();

     foreach (SelectedObject so in ss.Value)
      {

         Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(so.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

          if (!(ent is Solid3d))
           {
        ent.Explode(objs);
            ent.UpgradeOpen();
            ent.Erase();
          }
       }
   tr.Commit();
    }

 }
```

As soon as the control comes on to the ent.Erase() statement - it throws an exception, **eCannotBeErasedByCaller**. I cant figure out why? I have unlocked all layers, opened the entity for Write, CommandFlags have been set to Session and UsePickSet (shuffled through all).

Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you aim here, the code works fine here, it explodes all non-solid entities (in memory) and erase the original. after that, the drawing has no entities (empty), except solids.

Comment: When you have (1) proxy objects that require enabler (like objects from SysCAD or Athena) or you have (2) objects from AutoCAD Revit (or another from the AutoCAD vertical) than you cant simply just explode and erase because they have resident DbObjects that sometimes reference graphical objects, layers, etc. and they are not so easy to erase :)

Comment: Thanks Ognyan..!! wasnt aware of that. I changed the flow of my program,  things are working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason why the Original objects werent getting erased.

In the earlier part of the code, a AutoCAD Plant3D dwg is exported to AutoCAD (**ExporttoAutoCAD** / Saveas), this was creating Proxy items. These cant be deleted manually or via code. 
**Only way is to explode the PipeLines and Inline assets before exporting the file.** This happens automatically if you export the file, but if you use saveas, you will have to explode the Pipe components before you export the file.

Wasted a lot of time understanding the cause, but finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your description, you probably need a recursive explode. Sometime ago I did a code around this, for other type of entities, but you can adjust it.

```
private List<DBObject> FullExplode(Entity ent)
{
  // final result
  List<DBObject> fullList = new List<DBObject>();

  // explode the entity
  DBObjectCollection explodedObjects = new DBObjectCollection();
  ent.Explode(explodedObjects);
  foreach (Entity explodedObj in explodedObjects)
  {
    // if the exploded entity is a blockref or mtext
    // then explode again
    if (explodedObj.GetType() == typeof(BlockReference) ||
        explodedObj.GetType() == typeof(MText))
    {
      fullList.AddRange(FullExplode(explodedObj));
    }
    else
      fullList.Add(explodedObj);
  }
  return fullList;
}
```

source: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/infrastructure/2013/04/get-cogopoint-label-text.html

Comment: Hi Augusto, Thanks for the tip, and I think I forgot to mention.. below this code I add the newly created explodedObjs (DBObjectCollection) into the database and then recursively call the function again till there in nothing left to explode. But I cant seem to erase the original object (the object we explode). I keep getting that exception for PipeLines and InlineAssets in AutoCAD Plant3D